# Cron CloudWatch Monitoring Scripts Error on Amazon Linux AMI: Use of uninitialized value $data_value in scalar chomp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html) and configured cloudwatch monitoring scripts to run via a cron job on my instance. The scripts run, but I keep getting the following error mailed to me (on the MAILTO address in the crontab file):

```
mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used-incl-cache-buff --mem-used --mem-avail --aggregated --auto-scaling --from-cron
Use of uninitialized value $data_value in scalar chomp at /home/ec2-user/aws-scripts-mon/CloudWatchClient.pm line 137
```

I am using an IAM role instead of the credential file and the role has all the permissions mentioned in the link above.

While troubleshooting, I found:

1. The job is submitting data to cloudwatch and I confirm that I can see all the metrics in cloudwatch console.
2. There are no errors in /var/log/messages
3. If I run the script manually with the `--verbose` flag, I get a success message as well:

`print() on closed filehandle MDATA at CloudWatchClient.pm line 167.
    print() on closed filehandle MDATA at CloudWatchClient.pm line 167. 
    print() on closed filehandle MDATA at CloudWatchClient.pm line 167.
    MemoryUtilization: 15.9675544623621 (Percent) 
    MemoryUsed: 1275.01171875 (Megabytes) 
    MemoryAvailable: 6710.00390625 (Megabytes) 
    print() on closed filehandle MDATA at CloudWatchClient.pm line 167. 
    No credential methods are specified. Trying default IAM role. Using IAM role <xxxx-prod-WebServerRole-1891EV5KJYJ49> 
    Endpoint: https://monitoring.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 
    Payload: {    /*Removed for brevity*/ } 
    Received HTTP status 200 on attempt 1
    Successfully reported metrics to CloudWatch.
    Reference Id: c44c28ff-63e7-11e7-903d-350b8f4c0dae`

The error is intermittent but regular - I received the emails at 12:30 PM, 13:21 PM, 14:02 PM, 14:48 PM, 15:16 PM

Not sure what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You probably are running two mon-put-instance-data.pl commands simultaneously. CloudWatchClient.pm reads and writes to a temporary file in a manner that can break if multiple copies are run at once. The breakage would only be sporadic, because it depends on the exact ordering of the race.

One fix is to use [flock](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) in your cron command to ensure mutual exclusion when running mon-put-instance-data.pl:

```
flock -w 30 /tmp/mon-put-instance-data.lockfile mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used-incl-cache-buff --mem-used --mem-avail --aggregated --auto-scaling --from-cron
```